# Remove selected filters from Nested and Aggregation in Elasticsearh to perform filtered search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to use elasticsearch (VERSION 7.8.0) to perform Faceted search and have gotten something to work. However I want to remove the selected filters from my returned aggregations. E.g. If I had a shop selling clothes and I filter the products by colour: red Then I don't want colour: red to appear in my aggregations as that has been selected already.

To perform my filters I have the following Nested field on my example products:

```
"search_filters" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
        "key" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "value" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
     }
 },
```

So if I had data like

```
 "search_filters" : [
     {
         "key" : "colour",
         "value" : "red"
     }
 ]
```

I then perform a search like:

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "search_filters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "search_filters.key": "colour"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "search_filters.value": "red"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filters": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "search_filters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "search_keys": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "search_filters.key"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "search_values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "search_filters.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the right documents but my aggregations shows colour: red E.g.

```
{
  ...
  "filters": {
    "doc_count": 31,
    "search_keys": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "colour",
          "doc_count": 31,
          "search_values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "red",
                "doc_count": 31
              }
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to exclude these from elasticsearch or do I have to manually parse and ignore/remove my selected filters?

I have seen the use of filter in the aggregation field part of the request but I couldn't get that to work with my filter field; especially when I applied more than one filter e.g. colour and size.

Comment: do you want to exclude those results which are having `"search_filters.value": "red"` ?

Comment: I want products that have the colour red in my returned documents. However I want elasticsearch to not include that in the aggregations. Basically the aggregation is not aware that I have already filtered the documents by red, if that makes sense. To be honest it might not be possible or maybe I am using completely the wrong options; not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter aggregation, to exclude those results that match with `"search_filters.key": "colour"` `"search_filters.value": "red"`. This can contain additional musts for additional filters.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "search_filters",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "search_filters.key": "colour"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "search_filters.value": "red"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filters": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "search_filters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filterResult": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "search_filters.key": "colour"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "search_filters.value": "red"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "search_keys": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "search_filters.key"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "search_values": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "search_filters.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.8754687,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66222818",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8754687,
        "_source": {
          "search_filters": [
            {
              "key": "colour",
              "value": "red"                 // note this
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "filters": {
      "doc_count": 1,
      "filterResult": {
        "doc_count": 0,
        "search_keys": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": []                                // note this
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @PanPipes may I know why filter aggregation didn't work for you?

Comment: Ok I think I was not using filterResult and was just trying to add filter a level higher. Let me go try the above with more filters and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Ok so this is close and along the right lines thanks. However if say I have another filter with a different key but the same value. E.g. highlight-colour: red, I will lose that information in the aggregation Any ideas? I think this is where I got stuck before, so doing a must not with "AND"

Comment: @PanPipes can you please explain with an example so that it would be easier for me to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Don't worry I solved it by using additional level of bool and musts inside the must_not. So thanks your answer got me where I needed to go!

Comment: I have edited your answer slightly to just match my requirements. Hopefully the change will help explain but again thanks for your help it was much appreciated.